# Only execute WPF MouseDoubleClick event when DataGrid row is clicked

Tags: wpf, datagrid, double-click

I have a DataGrid in WPF. When I double-click on a row, a query to a database should be executed.

This DataGrid has horizontal and vertical scroll bars, and I notice that when I click quickly on the arrow button of one of the scroll bars, it sends the query to the database.

The problem is that I am using the DataGrid's `MouseDoubleClick` event, so the scroll bars belong the the DataGrid, and when they are double-clicked, this event is raised.

Is there any way to execute the double click event only when I double click on a row of the DataGrid and not when I double-click on part of the scroll bars?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your MouseDoubleClick event try doing this:

```
private void DataGridMouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    DependencyObject src = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent((DependencyObject)e.OriginalSource);

    // Checks if the user double clicked on a row in the datagrid [ContentPresenter]
    if (src.GetType() == typeof(ContentPresenter))
    {
        // Your logic..
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this will not work. There are many ContentPresenter in DataGrid (not only for rows) and you can't be sure that a ContentPresenter is a direct Parent of e.OriginalSource.

Comment: I have used this approach with success before. The point is that if the direct Parent of e.OriginalSource is a ContentPresenter you can assume the user clicked on a row or an object in one of the columns of that row and thus you can get the selected row. If it is something else, like a Border or Grid, just ignore it. Do you have any examples where this could go wrong?

Comment: I havn't tried. This was my thinking only. I mean a ContentPresenter is not an indication for a row. Does that really not fire on ColumnHeaders and ScrollBars? And what if Template isn't default?

Comment: The Parent of a ColumnHeader is Grid and ScrollBar is either RepeatButton or Thumb. I guess you could probably edit the Template to produce undesired results with this method, but I'm sure you could just adjust it accordingly? I haven't been able to make it fail yet, but I don't know if this way of doing it is bullet proof. If it isn't I would like to know :)

Comment: ContentPresenter Don't Work (There are many ContentPresenter in DataGrid es: Headers)

Comment: @Xilmiki to eliminate the ContentPresenters in the headers as hits just check if the visual parent of the ContentPresenter is a DataGridHeaderBorder. If it is, ignore the hit.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, register the event in `RowStyle`.

```
<DataGrid.RowStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
        <EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseDoubleClick" Handler="Row_PreviewMouseDoubleClick" />
    </Style>
</DataGrid.RowStyle>
```

Comment: What is the overhead of adding an eventsetter to every row in the data grid?

Comment: I think nothing to speak of because there is only one handler instance for all rows.

Comment: Well done!  Works great and I see no performance degradation (in regards what Mark asked).